# Pegar parametros de um RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo um APP onde mostra para o usuário as atividades a serem feitas num `RecyclerView`. Caso ele queira detalhes da atividade ele pode clicar e ver mais como descrição, nome e etc.

Agora estou com o seguinte problema pegar os dados da AnimeActivity e passar o "name" para a tela IniciaRelatorio alguém consegue me da uma luz ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: Olá, tente remover seu código de click do método "onCreateViewHolder" para o onBindViewHolder. Melhorias que você pode fazer: Crie uma interface e remova o código do seu adapter, segundo: faça que o objeto de sua lista implemente a interface parcelable ou serializable ficara melhor para enviar os dados via bundle além de diminuir bastante seu código.

Comment: Mas para eu pegar as variáveis e inserir em outra tela seria como ? Teria como me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixe-me tentar sintetizar o que o Alessandro Barreto te disse.

#### Faça sua classe Anime implementar Serializable

```
public class Anime implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private double rating;
    // ...

    public Anime() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // ...   
}
```

#### Deixe o onCreateViewHolder desta forma:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.anime_row_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}
```

#### onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Supondo que mData é uma lista de animes (List<Anime>)
    Anime anime = mData.get(position);

    holder.tv_name.setText(anime.getName());
    holder.tv_rating.setText(anime.getRating());
    holder.tv_studio.setText(anime.getStudio());
    holder.tv_category.setText(anime.getCategorie());

    // Load Image from the internet and set it into Imageview using Glide
    // Edit: o que é option aqui?        
    Glide.with(mContext).load(anime.getImage_url()).apply(option).into(holder.img_thumbnail);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> { // Java 8
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AnimeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("extra_anime", anime);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    });
}
```

#### AnimeActivity#onCreate:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Anime anime = (Anime) intent.getSerializableExtra("extra_anime");

    if (anime != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, anime.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Nenhum dado foi recebido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // finish();
    }
```

Comment: Esta dando um erro na parte:      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> { // Java 8
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AnimeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("extra_anime", anime);
             activity.startActivity(intent);   // TA DANDO ERRO no "activity"

Comment: *activity* é o contexto usado para chamar startActivity(). Use o contexto que passou para o seu adapter.

Comment: Quando escrevo "activity" ele da erro não reconhecendo a palavra

Comment: Use o contexto que passou para o seu adapter. (mContext)

Comment: Entendi, mas por exemplo quero pegar os dados de um RecyclerView ai puxaria pelo name como faria pra na outra tela pegar as informações dele ?

Comment: É a última parte da resposta. Recupere os dados no intent que iniciou a AnimeActivity. Mas apenas de um anime.

Comment: Ae por exemplo to no arquivo IniciaRelatorio.java vou colocar o getIntent igual ao arquivo AnimeActivity#onCreate:

Comment: Quero que quando o cara clicar em um, ele direcione para outra tela pegando as informações do AnimeActivity selecionado, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Se alguém tiver como me da uma luz agora na dúvida de cima please

Comment: Parece que você precisa de muita orientação. O código que postei faz exatamente isso. Quando você clica em um item da RecyclerView (holder.itemView), inicia uma activity passando no intent o Anime (Serializable). Você envia junto todos os dados do anime naquela posição da lista, de acordo com sua classe modelo Anime (primeira parte da pergunta). Na activity que é iniciada, recupera o objeto anime via getSerializableExtra().

Comment: Desculpa ta perguntando muito mas é porque assim que consigo entender e fazer para no futuro estar ajudando as pessoas também. Minha dúvida é a seguinte já consegui fazer isso orientado por você acima. Agora preciso que quando a pessoa escolha um item e clique no botão pegue informações ex: nome, na classe IniciarRelatorio. parei na parte: xtContrato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_contrato); Intent intent = getIntent(); Anime anime = (Anime) intent.getSerializableExtra("extra_anime"); txtContrato.setText(anime.getName())

Comment: So que nesse código acima ele não passa nenhum valor no txtContrato fico em branco.

Comment: No segundo screenshot, na `AnimeActivity`, você colocou no extra tv_name.toString(). Você deve colocar o próprio objeto Anime. No terceiro, em `IniciarVisita` você recuperou o objeto fazendo cast pra AnimeActivity, deve ser só Anime. PS: Não poste screenshots com código, poste o código inteiro na pergunta, não temos como saber se tem algo errado em outra parte do código e se alguém estiver disposto a te ajudar, terá que redigitar todo o código.

Comment: No caso o objeto anime seria descrito como ?

Comment: A classe anime está "descrita" como *exemplo* no início da resposta. No onBindViewHolder `Anime anime = mData.get(position);` -> `intent.putExtra("extra_anime", anime)`. A próxima activity (AnimeActivity) recebe o objeto Anime. Se quiser passá-lo dessa activity para outra, faça outro intent e coloque-o novamente no putExtra. Nessa próxima activity, use Anime animeRecebido = (Anime) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("extra_anime")